# rsync log file gets corrupted when using nano editor or mail ( postfix ) command

Tags: rsync, postfix, mail, html, nano

I have a strange situation where I am re-directing the whole output of an rsync command to a file and the file gets corrupted if I open it with nano editor or if I send the output to outlook mail.
If I use cat command , it looks ok :

`cat rsync_log.txt`

```
file1.sql
          5.04G 100%   20.80MB/s    0:03:51 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1)

sent 568.29K bytes  received 292.02M bytes  854.27K bytes/sec
total size is 5.04G  speedup is 17.24
receiving incremental file list
```

However , if I open the file with nano , it looks like this :

```
file1.sql
receiving incremental file list
^M              0   0%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00  ^M         13.85M   0%   12.31MB/s    0:06:39  ^M         51.85M   1%   23.87MB/s    0:03:24  ^M         76.78M   1%   2$
```

Furthermore, if I send the content of the file, wrapped in  html tags, to an outlook mail ( and this is what I really need ), it looks like this :

`cat rsync_log_wrapped_in_html.html | mail -a "Content-Type: text/html" -s "test" mail@example.com`

```
file.sql
              0   0%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00           13.85M   0%   12.31MB/s    0:06:39           51.85M   1%   23.87MB/s    0:03:24           76.78M   1%   22.75MB/s    0:03:33           96.60M   1%   20.77MB/s    0:03:52          104.91M   2%   19.69MB/s    0:04:04          110.95M   2%   12.75MB/s    0:06:17          114.65M   2%    8.40MB/s    0:09:32          124.31M   2%    6.39MB/s    0:12:31          141.71M   2%    8.52MB/s    0:09:22          156.63M   3%   10.48MB/s    0:07:35          163.16M   3%   11.12MB/s    0:07:08          187.10M   3%   14.58MB/s    0:05:25          203.72M   4%   14.50MB/s    0:05:26          209.76M   4%   12.57MB/s    0:06:15          213.88M   4%   11.49MB/s    0:06:50          217.93M   4%    6.91MB/s    0:11:22          222.47M   4%    3.94MB/s    0:19:55          234.70M   4%    5.18MB/s    0:15:06          238.46M   4%    5.24MB/s    0:14:56          243.78M   4%    5.57MB/s    0:14:01          257.35M   5%    8.02MB/
 s    0:09:43          264.74M   5%    6.92MB/s    0:11:14          269.72M   5%    7.19MB/s    0:10:48          283.57M   5%    9.14MB/s    0:08:28          315.04M   6%   13.28MB/s    0:05:47          336.63M   6%   16.33MB/s    0:04:41          352.96M   6%   19.35MB/s    0:03:56          357.15M   7%   16.98MB/s    0:04:29          360.49M   7%   10.19MB/s    0:07:28          369.80M   7%    7.57MB/s    0:10:02          386.99M   7%    7.37MB/s    0:10:16          402.76M   7%    9.96MB/s    0:07:34          411.99M   8%   10.33MB/s    0:07:17          422.93M   8%    9.82MB/s    0:07:39          430.88M   8%    7.49MB/s    0:10:01          457.08M   9%    9.26MB/s    0:08:03          511.61M  10%   18.69MB/s    0:03:56          582.41M  11%   32.66MB/s    0:02:13          615.00M
```

The output is a lot longer, this is only a fraction of it.
The file contains also other outputs/logs, which are viewed ok by nano, and sent ok with mail command.
Only the rsync part gets messed up. I deleted the file and created a new one, no change. I don't know what's happening , it's really disappointing. And I really need to send that output clear in html page to outlook , please help, thanks.

Comment: Is that also the case if you open the file with the default text editor? Press left windows (super) key and type `text` in the search box as opposed to using nano.

Comment: "re-directing the whole output of an rsync command to a file" — could you also include how this redirecting is done?

Comment: The output from rsync contains both the actual text from the progress, which you normally see updating on the screen, and the codes needed to do this in-line (codes for "go to start of line", "go one line up" and what else is needed to generate that one line running progress status). The options v and q (verbose and quiet) controlsh ow chatty rsync is. Try removing `v` and maybe add `q` to get rid of the inline progress bar.

Comment: the default editor is nano, output is redirected like this : ``` script.sh > rsync_log.txt 2>&1  ``` ,  from crontab

Comment: rsync command is like this : ``` rsync -avzhe  --progress server@ip ```

Comment: I will remove the --progress option, and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved, I removed --progress option from rsync command, that option cannot be included in the log without messing up the whole file. Thanks everyone for helping me find the solution.